# jQuery Set Select Index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an select box:

```
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Number 0</option>
  <option value="1">Number 1</option>
  <option value="2">Number 2</option>
  <option value="3">Number 3</option>
  <option value="4">Number 4</option>
  <option value="5">Number 5</option>
  <option value="6">Number 6</option>
  <option value="7">Number 7</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to set one of the options as "selected" based on it's selected index.

For example, if I am trying to set "Number 3", I'm trying this:

```
$('#selectBox')[3].attr('selected', 'selected');
```

But this doesn't work.  How can I set an option as selected based on it's index using jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as you previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280369/jquery-set-selected-option-using-next

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Answer (score 470):

**NOTE**: answer is dependent upon jQuery 1.6.1+

```
$('#selectBox :nth-child(4)').prop('selected', true); // To select via index
$('#selectBox option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);  // To select via value
```

---

Thanks for the comment, `.get` won't work since it returns a DOM element, not a jQuery one. Keep in mind the `.eq` function can be used outside of the selector as well if you prefer.

```
$('#selectBox option').eq(3).prop('selected', true);
```

---

You can also be more terse/readable if you want to use the *value*, instead of relying on selecting a specific *index*:

```
$("#selectBox").val("3");
```

**Note:** `.val(3)` works as well for this example, but non-numeric values must be strings, so I chose a string for consistency. 
*(e.g. `<option value="hello">Number3</option>` requires you to use `.val("hello")`)*

Comment: +1 - The second option worked for me.  The chosen answer by John Kugelman did not work for me in IE7.

Comment: Sadly, none of these ways fire a change() event for me.  I have   $('#selectBox').change(function() { alert('changed') });

Comment: @mikejones - that's by design.  When you're programmatically setting a selected option, you may not always want the bound change event to be triggered (like on a page load event.) To solve that jquery leaves it up to the developer to decide.  In your case you can simply call $('#selectBox').change(); after you have called $('#selectBox').val("3");

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Marcus.  Glad to know its not a bug.

Comment: +1 $('#selectBox option').eq(3).attr('selected', 'selected'); works excellent!

Comment: The 3rd option was simple and effective

Comment: Is the first option 0 or 1?

Comment: @LeeMeador If I understand your question, the first option is `0` when using `eq(index)`. When you use `nth-child(index)` *there are other uses such as `even`, `odd`, etc*, you start with the index `1`.

Comment: I thought it worth mentioning that post-jQuery 1.6.1, the recommended method for modifying boolean properties of an element is `.prop()` rather than `.attr()`.

Comment: @DevlshOne absolutely right, forgot all about this question. Updated to show `.prop` since `.attr` doesn't always work post 1.9.1 anyway. Modifying the property is the correct usage anyway (whether pojs or jquery)

Comment: Using jQuery Mobile don't forget to update the UI so your selection displays. $('#select').selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh');

Comment: As noted earlier, the nth-child selectors are "1-indexed" rather than the typical 0 index. So to select the first list item, use :nth-child(1). See https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/.

Answer (score 118):

This may also be useful, so I thought I'd add it here.

If you would like to select a value based on the item's value and not the index of that item then you can do the following:

Your select list:

```
<select id="selectBox">
    <option value="A">Number 0</option>
    <option value="B">Number 1</option>
    <option value="C">Number 2</option>
    <option value="D">Number 3</option>
    <option value="E">Number 4</option>
    <option value="F">Number 5</option>
    <option value="G">Number 6</option>
    <option value="H">Number 7</option>
</select>
```

The jquery:

```
$('#selectBox option[value=C]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

```
$('#selectBox option[value=C]').prop('selected', true);
```

The selected item would be "Number 2" now.

Comment: note: there's an extra underscore after the $()... otherwise, this works fantastically

Comment: +1 I couldn't get this to work exactly, but from this I finally got it to work with this following syntax:    $("#selectBox option[value='C']")[0].selected = true;

Comment: Just be aware that `.attr('selected', 'selected')` should not be used several times on the same select, as some browsers can get confused (in some cases they start marking several items in the dom as `selected=selected"`. If you need to change the selected value more often (e.g. on a button click) use `.prop('selected', true)` as suggested by Marc. - Is just had a lot pain - and wasted time - because of this issue!

Comment: This    $('#selectBox option[value=C]').prop('selected', true);  worked like a charm.

Answer (score 68):

Try this instead:

```
$("#selectBox").val(3);
```

Comment: This makes copying from one element to another dead simple as well!

Comment: typo: after "selectBox you're missing a quote

Comment: This is simple and straightforward. I much prefer this solution.

Comment: This works in Chrome, but doesn't work for me with IE9. I use: $('#selectBox option')[3].selected = true; (seans answer).

Comment: FWIW, This doesn't even work in Chrome for me.  Using the ":nth-child" answer worked for me.

Comment: @JayTaylor It works fine for me in Chrome (33.0). What version where you using at the time of your comment, do you know?

Answer (score 53):

Even simpler:

```
$('#selectBox option')[3].selected = true;
```

Comment: This worked for me, I also needed to select by INDEX not VALUE.

Comment: This answer gave me what i needed.. I was missing the 'option' part of the selector when trying to select by name $('select[name="select_name"] option)[index].selected=true;

Answer (score 17):

```
# Set element with index
$("#select option:eq(2)").attr("selected", "selected");

# Set element by text
$("#select").val("option Text").attr("selected", "selected");
```

when you want to select with top ways for set selection , you can use
`$('#select option').removeAttr('selected');` for remove previous selects .

```
# Set element by value
$("#select").val("2");

# Get selected text
$("#select").children("option:selected").text();  # use attr() for get attributes
$("#select option:selected").text(); # use attr() for get attributes 

# Get selected value
$("#select option:selected").val();
$("#select").children("option:selected").val();
$("#select option:selected").prevAll().size();
$("option:selected",this).val();

# Get selected index
$("#select option:selected").index();
$("#select option").index($("#select option:selected"));

# Select First Option
$("#select option:first");

# Select Last Item
$("#select option:last").remove();


# Replace item with new one
$("#select option:eq(1)").replaceWith("<option value='2'>new option</option>");

# Remove an item
$("#select option:eq(0)").remove();
```

Comment: +1 for : $('#select option').removeAttr('selected'); simplest option to return 'selected' item to top, or no defined selection.

Answer (score 11):

What's important to understand is that `val()` for a `select` element returns the value of the selected option, but not the number of element as does `selectedIndex` in javascript.

To select the option with `value="7"` you can simply use:

```
$('#selectBox').val(7); //this will select the option with value 7.
```

To deselect the option use an empty array:

```
$('#selectBox').val([]); //this is the best way to deselect the options
```

And of course you can select multiple options*:

```
$('#selectBox').val([1,4,7]); //will select options with values 1,4 and 7
```

*However to select multiple options, your `<select>` element must have a `MULTIPLE` attribute, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 11):

I've always had issues with prop('selected'), the following has always worked for me:

```
//first remove the current value
$("#selectBox").children().removeAttr("selected");
$("#selectBox").children().eq(index).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$('select#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex', optionIndex);
```

Eventually, trigger a .change event :

```
$('select#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex', optionIndex).change();
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope this could help Too

```
$('#selectBox option[value="3"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 5):

The pure javascript [selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) attribute is the right way to go because,it's pure javascript and works cross-browser:

```
$('#selectBox')[0].selectedIndex=4;
```

[Here is a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6QNeW/2/) with two dropdowns using one to set the other:

```
<select onchange="$('#selectBox')[0].selectedIndex=this.selectedIndex">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Number 0</option>
  <option value="1">Number 1</option>
  <option value="2">Number 2</option>
</select>
```

You can also call this before changing the selectedIndex if what you want is the "selected" attribute on the option tag ([here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6QNeW/3/)):

```
$('#selectBox option').removeAttr('selected')
   .eq(this.selectedIndex).attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 5):

select 3rd option

```
$('#selectBox').val($('#selectBox option').eq(2).val());
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dabar/jwNyV/)

Answer (score 4):

NB:

```
$('#selectBox option')[3].attr('selected', 'selected')
```

is incorrect, the array deference gets you the dom object, not a jquery object, so it will fail with a TypeError, for instance in FF with: "$('#selectBox option')[3].attr() not a function."

Answer (score 4):

In 1.4.4 you get an error:  *$("#selectBox option")[3].attr is not a function*

This works: `$('#name option:eq(idx)').attr('selected', true);`

Where `#name` is select id and `idx` is the option value you want selected.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify Marc's and John Kugelman's answers, you could use:

```
$('#selectBox option').eq(3).attr('selected', 'selected')
```

`get()` will not work if used in the way specified because it gets the DOM object, not a jQuery object, so the following solution will not work:

```
$('#selectBox option').get(3).attr('selected', 'selected')
```

`eq()` gets filters the jQuery set to that of the element with the specified index. It's  clearer than `$($('#selectBox  option').get(3))`. It's not all that efficient. `$($('#selectBox option')[3])` is more efficient (see [test case](http://jsperf.com/jquery-eq)).

You don't actually need the jQuery object though. This will do the trick:

```
$('#selectBox option')[3].selected = true;
```

http://api.jquery.com/get/

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

## One other vitally important point:

The attribute "selected" is not how you specify a selected radio button (in Firefox and Chrome at least). Use the "checked" attribute:

```
$('#selectBox option')[3].checked = true;
```

The same goes for check-boxes.

Answer (score 4):

I often use trigger ('change') to make it work

```
$('#selectBox option:eq(position_index)').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

Example with id select = selectA1 and position_index = 0 (frist option in select):

```
$('#selectA1 option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//funcion para seleccionar por el text del select
var text = '';
var canal = ($("#name_canal").val()).split(' ');
$('#id_empresa option').each(function(i, option) {
        text = $('#id_empresa option:eq('+i+')').text();
        if(text.toLowerCase() == canal[0].toLowerCase()){
            $('#id_empresa option:eq('+i+')').attr('selected', true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectBox option').get(3).attr('selected', 'selected')
```

When using the above I kept getting errors in webkit (Chrome) saying:

"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'attr'"

This syntax stops those errors.

```
$($('#selectBox  option').get(3)).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to select an item based of a particular property of an item then jQuery option of type[prop=val] will get that item. Now I don't care about the index I just wanted the item by its value.

```
$('#mySelect options[value=3]).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

I need a solution that has no hard coded values in the js file; using `selectedIndex`. Most of the given solutions failed one browser. This appears to work in FF10 and IE8 (can someone else test in other versions)

```
$("#selectBox").get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the item based on the value in the select list (especially if the option values have a space or weird character in it) by simply doing this:

```
$("#SelectList option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1:00 PM")
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Also, if you have a dropdown (as opposed to a multi-select) you may want to do a `break;` so you don't get the first-value-found to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem. 
First you need go through the events (i.e which event is happening first).

For example:

The **First event**  is generating select box with options.

The **Second event** is selecting default option using any function such as val() etc.

You should ensure that the **Second event** should happen after the **First event**.

To achieve this take two functions lets say **generateSelectbox()** (for genrating select box) and **selectDefaultOption()**

You need to ensure that **selectDefaultOption()** should be called only after the execution of **generateSelectbox()**

Answer (score 1):

You can also init multiple values if your selectbox is a multipl:

```
$('#selectBox').val(['A', 'B', 'C']);
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending too much time, this one worked for me.

```
$("#selectbox")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  set selectoption variable  value dynamically as well as option will be selected.You can try following code

code:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
      $(function(){
            $('#allcheck').click(function(){
             // $('#select_option').val([1,2,5]);also can use multi selectbox
              // $('#select_option').val(1);
               var selectoption=3;
           $("#selectBox>option[value="+selectoption+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });

});
```

HTML CODE:

```
   <select id="selectBox">
       <option value="0">Number 0</option>
       <option value="1">Number 1</option>
       <option value="2">Number 2</option>
       <option value="3">Number 3</option>
       <option value="4">Number 4</option>
       <option value="5">Number 5</option>
       <option value="6">Number 6</option>
       <option value="7">Number 7</option>
 </select> <br>
<strong>Select&nbsp;&nbsp; <a style="cursor:pointer;" id="allcheck">click for select option</a></strong>
```

Answer (score -2):

Shortly:

`$("#selectBox").attr("selectedIndex",index)`

where index is the selected index as integer.

Comment: this code works
 $('#selectBox').prop({selectedIndex:desiredIndex})