# jquery select option not working (by name)

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML which defines my selector:

```
<select name="zoom_cat[]" style="margin-left:15px;">
  <option value="-1" selected="selected">All</option>
  <option value="0">News</option>
  <option value="1">Publications</option>
  <option value="2">Services</option>
  <option value="3">Industries</option>
</select>
```

And I am trying to set the selected option to All (value -1).  For some reason this jquery code is having no effect (same option remains selected):

```
$('input[name="zoom_cat[]"] option[value="-1"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280499/jquery-set-select-index/ duplicate

Comment: You're trying to set the `select` element (despite using `input` in the selector) to the value of the `option` that's already selected, and you're surprised that it doesn't change anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('select[name="zoom_cat[]"] option[value="-1"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

instead of `input`

Comment: `selected` is a property (`prop()`), not an attribute. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L7BkN/).

Comment: @DavidThomas, prop and attr both work, if you use them right. It's not wrong to use attr here. Changing the selected attribute also changes the property automatically and vise versa.
`.attr('selected'): selected` `.prop('selected'): true`

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` instead of `input`

```
$('select[name="zoom_cat[]"] option[value="-1"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Est9D/4/

You can do it in more simple way

```
  $('select[name="zoom_cat[]"]').val("-1")
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Est9D/7/

Answer (score 0):

As Matt above said, you should use `select` in your selector, not `input`, they are different elements. Also setting the selected attribute will not work on <=IE7, so ideally you should do `$('select[name="zoom_cat[]"]').val('-1');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters in your selector.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

So try this instead:

```
$('input[name="zoom_cat\\\\[\\\\]"] option[value="-1"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: You must escape square brackets in a jquery selector for it to work correctly in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: (not attr as suggested by someone but prop)

```
$('select[name="zoom_cat[]"] option[value="-1"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
```