# jquery selecting option from

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following option box:

```
<label for="inputselection1">Input #1:</label>
<select id="inputselection1" name="unittype">
<option value="1">Miner</option>
<option value="2">Puffer</option>
<option value="3">Snipey</option>
<option value="4">Max</option>
<option value="5">Firebot</option>
</select><br>
```

however, when I execute the following jquery option onload, the text (selected option) does not get changed to Max:

```
$("#inputselection1 option[text=Max]").attr("selected","selected");
```

What gives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val()` to set select value by option value:

```
$("#inputselection1").val(4);​
```

If you insist on selecting by text, then use this:

```
$("#inputselection1 option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'Max';
}).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select by option text you can use a [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function

```
$("#inputselection1 option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'Max';
}).prop("selected", true);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8CBvZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

$("#inputselection1 option[value=4]").attr("selected","selected");

taken from

[jQuery Set Select Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280499/jquery-set-select-index)