# How can I change selected value of a DropDownList with having change method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it's possible to get jQuery to select an option with having predefined change method.

Let me give me an example; I have a drop-down list like this:

```
<select id="ddl_BankRequestType">
    <option>-- Request Type ---</option>
    <option value="val1">Item1</option>
    <option value="val2">Item2</option>
</select>
```

If user selects *Item1* or *Item2* some logic will be executed:

```
$('#ddl_BankRequestType').change(function () {
     var selectedItem = $(this).find(":selected").text();
     if (selectedItem === 'Item1') {
         // codes
     } else if (selectedItem === 'Item2') {
         //other codes
     }
});
```

It works like a charm. Now in `document.ready` I want the second option be selected item, so I put this code:

```
$('#ddl_BankRequestType > option:eq(2)').attr('selected', true);
```

It also works, but I want the logic for *Item2* to execute.  I have tried the following, but they do nothing:

```
$('#ddl_BankRequestType > option:eq(2)').attr('selected', true).change();
$('#ddl_BankRequestType > option:eq(2)').attr('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: It works on my machine. Can you share on jsfiddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280499/jquery-set-select-index . That answer uses `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hroxj3ry/ you can check from here!

Comment: @guvenckardas It works but it doesn't execute code for second if. http://jsfiddle.net/19kferho/

Comment: @JackA. My question isn't about How to Set Select Index.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi that is happening because `change` event is added **after** executing the line that selects the item.

Comment: But it works on here :http://jsfiddle.net/19kferho/1/ @SirwanAfifi

Comment: Just an FYI, it's better to use the `value` of the option as that is less likely to change than the `text`.  For instance, a person's name might change, but their SSN is less likely to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the code from [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/19kferho/1)

```
$(function (){
  $('#ddl_BankRequestType').change(function () {
      var selectedItem = $(this).find(":selected").text();

      console.log(selectedItem)
      if (selectedItem === 'Item1') {
        alert('item1');
      } else if (selectedItem === 'Item2') {
        alert('item2');
      }
  });

  $('#ddl_BankRequestType > option:eq(2)').attr('selected', true).change();        

});
```

Comment: :) It should have put the code after change method :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix should be something like below,

```js
$('#ddl_BankRequestType').on("change",function () {
     var selectedItem = $(this).find(":selected").text();
     if (selectedItem === 'Item1') {
 doItem1();
     } else if (selectedItem === 'Item2') {
 doItem2();
     }
});
function doItem1(){
 alert('Item1'); 
 //other codes
}
function doItem2(){
 alert('Item2');
 //other codes
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ddl_BankRequestType > option:eq(2)').attr('selected', true);
doItem2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl_BankRequestType">
    <option>-- Request Type ---</option>
    <option value="val1">Item1</option>
    <option value="val2">Item2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns a string.  So, you can't chain it to trigger the change event.  You could do the following:

```
   var ddl_BankRequestType = $('#ddl_BankRequestType');
   ddl_BankRequestType.find('option:eq(2)').attr('selected', true);
   ddl_BankRequestType.trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a timing issue - since theoretically your code *should* be firing that trigger event based on the way you're doing it. I think it's simply firing the event before the change function is registered. jQuery's Document load lifecycle loops through all of the defined loaders in the order they're registered, so if you're not able to change when you set the option element as "selected" to after the change event is bound, you may be able to use the native timeout function to ensure it gets fired last.

I generally avoid using timeout like this, but in your scenario it may work:

```
setTimeout(function() { /* Set the option element true here */ }, 1000);
```

Best bet is to try and set the element after the change event is bound.