# How to set .selectedIndex with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have some html selects:

```
<select class="form-control, dropdown" id="delperffrom" name="delperffrom">
. . .
<select class="form-control, dropdown" id="delperfto" name="delperfto">
. . .
```

I want to initialize them to "no value" and so have this javascript, which works:

```
document.getElementById("delperffrom").selectedIndex = -1;
```

..and this jQuery, which doesn't:

```
$("#delperfto").selectedIndex = -1;
```

Why does the jQuery not work?

Comment: because... `$()` doesn't return a dom node? read the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery -> http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

Comment: Unrelated but css classes are separated by spaces only.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/?s=selectedIndex shows that this property doesn't exist, but shows methods you can use to change `selectedIndex`.

Comment: Maybe `$("#delperfto")[0].selectedIndex = -1;` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Set Select Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280499/jquery-set-select-index)

Comment: Additionally, don't put commas in the class list: "form-control dropdown" is correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `.selectedindex` is property of the *DOM* element, not *jQuery*.You can change it on *DOM* element, or using *jQuery* **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**  method:

```
$("#delperffrom")[0].selectedIndex = -1; // change on dom element pulled from jQuery
$("#delperffrom").prop('selectedIndex',-1); // change with .prop() jquery method
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `$("#delperfto")` is NOT a DOM element.  It's a jQuery object and a jQuery object does not have a `.selectedIndex` property.  A jQuery object is its own type of object with its own properties and methods.  It does not have the same properties and methods as a DOM element.  It often has a way of accomplishing the same thing, but usually with different syntax.

You can either fetch a DOM element from the jQuery object and access that DOM element directly like this:

```
$("#delperfto")[0].selectedIndex = -1;
```

or

```
$("#delperfto").get(0).selectedIndex = -1;
```

Or, you can use jQuery's `.prop()` method to have it set the desired property on each DOM element for you like this:

```
$("#delperfto").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

There's no particular advantage to one or the other in this specific circumstance, but if your selector returned more than one element in it such as this:

```
$(".options").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

then the jQuery `.prop()` method would set that property on all DOM elements that the selector matched, not just the first one which can sometimes be quite useful.

Comment: Just wondering why both these answers got a downvote.  Seems odd.