# Trigger change events on two <select> elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

I have two `select` elements and would like to tigger a change event on both at the same time. With only **one** select element, I would do the following:

**HTML**

```
<select class="check">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.check').change(function(){
  var data= $(this).val();
  alert(data);            
});

$('.check').val('two').trigger('change');
```

Does anyone know how to set the **first** element (regardless of value) in **both** `select` elements?

```
<select class="check">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
</select>

<select class="check">
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option value="four">four</option>
</select>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That's what [`HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) is for

Comment: Likely duplicate: [Set select index with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280518/2181514)

Comment: `$("select").change()` will trigger both,  `$("select option:nth-child(2)")` to select the 2nd option across all `select`s.   `.prop("selected", true)` to set the option as selected (the jquery way, can also use selectedIndex as noted above).   https://jsfiddle.net/94ut376r/